# How to move listView cell up if its item are not fully visible

Tags: android, listview

I am working in android application which is using listview to populate its data,In the design   firstly list is shown with some of items, and on clicking on the cell it expands to show another part of the cell layout whose visiblity is "gone" on the creation of the cell.

Now if user clickes on the last cell of the listview it expands to show its invisible  layout but that goes below the visible window of the screen.Now what i want to do is if on expanding the list cell its content goes below the visible window scroll listview up automatically to show complete cell.

Please suggest a best way how can i achieve it?

Comment: please put your code when an item in the list is selected.

Comment: you try remove item from array [array.remove(position);]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure if it will work, but give it a shot:

```
listView.scrollTo(0, listView.getHeight());
```

Let me know.